# Не получается подключить VK API к Gradle intellij idea

Tags: java, vkontakte-api, intellij-idea, gradle

Intellij idea community 2022.1 , Gradle 7.5 , Project SDK 18.
При попытке добавить API VK получаю ошибку.

```
    dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    implementation 'com.vk.api:sdk:1.0.14'
}
```

[image: Trouble]

Подскажите пожалуйста, что я не так делаю?

Comment: Вы уверены, что ошибка именно в попытке подключения sdk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Проверка и сообщение об ошибке

Решил проверить и запустить проект с вашими зависимостями.

При запуске получил следующее сообщение в терминале:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/michaeldl/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl/2.17.2/183f7c95fc981f3e97d008b363341343508848e/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.17.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/michaeldl/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/1.2.11/4741689214e9d1e8408b206506cbe76d1c6a7d60/logback-classic-1.2.11.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.logging.log4j.LoggingException: log4j-slf4j-impl cannot be present with log4j-to-slf4j
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.validateContext(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:60)
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.newLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:44)
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.newLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:33)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getLogger(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:53)
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:33)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:363)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter$Slf4jAdapter.createLocationAwareLog(LogAdapter.java:130)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter.createLog(LogAdapter.java:91)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:67)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:59)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractApplicationContext.java:178)
    at org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext.<init>(GenericApplicationContext.java:114)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:67)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:91)
    at reversbot.Main.main(Main.java:12)
```

Главное, на что стоит обратить внимание:

> SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.

Другими словами в Ваших зависимостях(а если быть точнее то и `spring-boot-starter` и `vk-bot`) есть конфликтующие настройки систем логирования.

---

#### Что стоит сделать, для того чтобы это пофиксить?

Достаточно просто исключить конфликтующую зависимость.

В Вашем случае можно заменить

```
implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter')
```

на

```
implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter') {
    exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
}
```

В итоге блок зависимостей будет выглядеть так:

```
dependencies {
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter') {
        exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
    }
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    implementation 'com.vk.api:sdk:1.0.14'
}
```

После чего все опять начнет заводиться.

---

**Не забудьте обновить зависимости в gradle перед запуском!**

Comment: Да-да, оно работает.

Comment: Эта моя не внимательность.